# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xx

Tags: spring, rest, maven, osgi

I've searched entire SO, and although posts with the similar title exists this is a different scenario.

I've two projects in my eclipse 1) One JPA project 2) One Web project which consumes the entities from the JPA project. Both are OSGi and Maven enabled. I'm using the latest SpringFramework (3.1.1) for creating RESTful webservices in the Web project.

The project layouts are as follows:

1) JPA Project

```
com.demo.persistence 
|-src
  |-com.demo.persistence
    |-User
|-META-INF
    |-MANIFEST.MF
    |-persistence.xml
|-pom.xml
```

---

2) Web Project

```
com.demo.web
|-src
  |-com.demo.web.controller
    |-Controller.java
  |-com.demo.web.dao
    |-UserDAO.java
    |-UserListDAO.java
  |-com.demo.web.model
    |-UserBean.java
  |-com.demo.web.interfaces
    |-UserDAOIntf.java
|-WebContent
  |-META-INF
    |-MANIFEST.MF
  |-WEB-INF
    |-classes
      |-log4j.properties
    |-rest-context.xml
    |-rest-context-osgi.xml
    |-rest-servlet.xml
    |-web.xml
  |-pom.xml
```

---

com.demo.persistence.User.java

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
@Table(name = "T_USER")
@NamedQuery(name = "AllUsers", query = "select u from User u")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(nullable = false)
private long id;

@Basic
@Column(nullable = false)
private String userName;

public void setUserName(String param) {
    this.userName = param;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
}
```

---

com.demo.web.dao.UserDAO

```
public class UserDAO implements UserDAOInterface {  
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public User getUser(Long id) {
  try{
      return em.find(User.class, id);
  } finally {
      if(em != null)
      em.close();
   }
}

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
  try {
    List<User> users = em.createNamedQuery("AllUsers", User.class).getResultList();
    return users;
  } finally {
          if(em != null)
          em.close();
  }
}

@Transactional
public User addUser(User user) {
  try {
    em.persist(user);
        em.flush();
    return user;
        } finally {
        if(em != null)
    em.close();
        }
  }
}
```

---

com.demo.web.model

```
public class UserBean {
  private UserDAO userDAO;
    public void addUserDetails( String userName ) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName(userName);
    this.userDAO.addUser(user);
}

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return this.userDAO.getAllUsers();
}

public User getUser(Long id) {
    return this.userDAO.getUser(id);
}

public User addUser(User user) {    
    return this.userDAO.addUser(user);
}
}
```

---

com.demo.web.controller.Controller

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller;
    private UserBean userBean;

    public Jaxb2Marshaller getJaxb2Mashaller() {
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

    public void setJaxb2Mashaller(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller) {
        this.jaxb2Marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller;
    }
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/rest/users", headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public @ResponseBody UserListDAO getUserList() { 
        return new UserListDAO(userBean.getAllUsers());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="rest/user/{id}", headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userBean.getUser(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="rest/user/add", headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User addUser(@RequestBody String userString) {
        Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(userString));
        User user = (User) jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(source);
        return userBean.addUser(user);
    }
```

---

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>com.demo.web</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- The context params that read by ContextLoaderListener  -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/rest-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- This listener will load other application context file in addition to springweb-servlet.xml -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

rest-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.web.controller" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="com.demo.persistence" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>   

    <!-- Bean - DAO Mapping -->
    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.demo.dao.UserDAO">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Bean Declarations -->
    <bean id="userBean" class="com.demo.web.model.UserBean">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---

rest-context-osgi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.0.xsd">

    <osgi:service interface="javax.persistence.EntityManager" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

</beans>
```

---

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- To enable @RequestMapping process on type level and method level -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshallingConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.demo.persistence.User</value>
                <value>com.demo.dao.UserListDAO</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="users" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <!--bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" /-->

    <bean id="userController" class="com.demo.web.controller.Controller">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
        <property name="jaxb2Mashaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

Console - log4j

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named com.demo.persistence

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)

    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)

    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)

    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:131)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:154)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:143)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)

    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:122)

    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:91)

    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.extender.WebContainerBundleCustomizer.addingBundle(WebContainerBundleCustomizer.java:45)

    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:482)

    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)

    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)

    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:234)

    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:457)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1522)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework$7.run(Framework.java:1462)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1460)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1453)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:391)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.resumeBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:311)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:555)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:251)

    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:173)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named com.demo.persistence

    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)

    ... 45 more
```

---

Sorry for the huge post. But I export my persistence package in the Manifest file and import the same in my web app.

And the persistence provider used is `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`.
This has been stopping my project from a month.. :( Please help.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.demo.persistence"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.demo.persistence.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Could you post your persistence.xml, please ?

Comment: I've added my persistence.xml.

Comment: This is not a good question. See http://sscce.org for ways to improve it (and future question you might ask here).

Answer (score 1):

You are instructing your container to managed and initialize your persistence context for you:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

But it can only do this if it has access to the persistence.xml file in the same archive as where you are performing the entity manager initialization. In this case, you should probably move all your persistence logic into your persistence project (thats what you created it for after all). Alternatively you can copy your persistence.xml into the web project (not recommended).

Comment: Can I not split this into different projects? The DAO classes and the persistence units, into different projects. Actually even the dao classes need to b spli from the web project, i.e, the persistence, the dao classes, the web project where I use my controller in to different projects. Or is there any way to add the persistence project archive into my web project at compile/run time?

Comment: Whats your reason for needing that level of separation? At the end of the day your persistence.xml file will need to be located in the same archive as where you are initializing your entity manager. I highly recommend putting all the persistence classes in one project though (config file, entities, and DAO's).

Comment: The reason for that level of separation is this project might grow pretty big and it will be difficult to maintain and hence its needed. The last option if nothing works is what you are suggesting @Perception. But I really need it to be in the format that I have explained. Also, I tried the same on a non-Maven and a non-OSGi type of environment where the JPA project is put in the deployment assembly of the web project and that works. The JPA project is exported as a JAR file into the WAR file of the web project.